# Tableau summarizing different fields (similar to Countif-Function in Excel)

Tags: count, boolean, tableau-api

i am trying to build a data validation dashboard in Tableau.
We have an oracle data source, which contains one contains one relevant table.

I am adding calculated fields to the table, that check each row based on some logic. The resulting values are either true or false. The table structure is shown below.

```
+----+---+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| ID | … | Sanity Check 1 | Sanity Check 2 | Sanity Check 3 |
+----+---+----------------+----------------+----------------+
|  1 | … | TRUE           | FALSE          | TRUE           |
|  2 | … | TRUE           | FALSE          | FALSE          |
+----+---+----------------+----------------+----------------+
```

My goal is to create a sheet, with a table that counts the occurrences of each sanity check.

```
+-------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
|       | Sanity Check 1 | Sanity Check 2 | Sanity Check 3 |
+-------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
| TRUE  |              2 |              0 |              1 |
| FALSE |              0 |              2 |              1 |
+-------+----------------+----------------+----------------+
```

In Excel i would create this secondary table from scratch and use the Countif-Function to count the occurrences. Is it possible to duplicate this method in Tableau?
I have only a limited experience with Tableau, so i am unsure if i am missing some simple approach to this problem.

BR

Comment: Can the sanity checks for each row be calculated only based on the values in that specific row - independent of other rows? If so, you could use pivoting to create one column that listed which sanity checks each ID passed